# RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, high-availability

I have a cluster that consists of 4 nodes

- nn1
- nn2
- dn1
- dn2
- nn1, nn2 name node.

`node-01` is the hostname of `nn1`, `node-02` is the hostname of `nn2`.
When `nn1` is active, `nn2` is standby. I can successfully run a program on spark, like this:

```
 bin/spark-submit \
--class test.Test1 \
--master spark://node-01:7077 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--total-executor-cores 2 \
--executor-memory 1G \
--total-executor-cores 2 \
hdfs://node-01:9000/jar/a.jar
```

But when `nn1` is standby and `nn2` is active, there is an exception:

`{"RemoteException":{"message":"Operation category READ is not supported in state standby","exception":"RemoteException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException"}}`

How can I keep using the same command line when `nn1` and `nn2` change their status?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When HDFS runs in High Availability mode, you must use the appropriate syntax i.e. `hdfs://cluster_alias/jar/a.jar` where `cluster_alias` is defined in detail in _hdfs-site.xml_

Comment: ok，i know it，thanks.